# Rendering 'belongs_to" in index view question - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a simple blog application with Ruby on Rails. The applications consists of two tables, posts and comments. Comments `belongs_to :post` and posts `has_many :comments`.

I created posts table with the following columns: `title:string`, `body:text`.
I created the comments table with the following columns: `body:text` `post_id:integer` `name:string` `email:string`

In the /views/comments/index.html.erb display I would like to show a listing of all comments w/ the post title as well. Currently, the index view only displays post_id, body, name, email.

How do I replace the post_id column with the corresponding post title? Here is my code:

CommentsController Index action:

```
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all :order => "created_at DESC"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comments }
      format.json { render :json => @comments }
      format.atom
    end
  end
```

/views/comments/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing comments</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Post</th>
    <th>Body</th>
  </tr>

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h comment.post_id %></td>
    <td><%=h comment.body %></td>
    <td><%=h comment.name %></td>
    <td><%=h comment.email %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 100 comments, using `comments.post.title` with your code will result in **101** queries! See the [Eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) section on this docs page. Eager loading here will reduce it to **2**.

```
def index
  @comments = Comment.find(:all, :include => :post, :order => "created_at DESC")
  # ...
end
```

In your views, you can access the post title as

```
<%= comment.post.title rescue "No post" %>
```

---

**Edit:** I'm using `rescue "No Post"` because you have some comments with `post_id` = `nil` and some comments with `post_id` that point to posts that no longer exist.

Comment: I am still getting an error saying: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass. Any ideas?

Comment: @bgadoci, try running `script/console` in your terminal. Do `c = Comment.find(1)` followed by `c.post.inspect`. What do you see?

Comment: Ok, the first command returns this: #<Comment id: 1, post_id: nil, body: "test", created_at: "2010-04-10 04:49:54", updated_at: "2010-04-10 04:49:54", name: nil, email: nil>
The second command returns "nil".

Comment: because perhaps the first comment was before I had everything set up, I ran c = Comment.find(25) and it returned this: #<Comment id: 25, post_id: 6, body: "test", created_at: "2010-04-11 19:41:13", updated_at: "2010-04-11 19:41:13", name: nil, email: nil>
and then "nil" again for the second request.

Comment: c = Post.find(6) returns: ActiveRecord: :RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post with ID=6.

Comment: You should edit your question and add your models and create action wherever you're trying to associate the two. You may be creating your Post <-> Comment connections wrong if Comment 25 lists a post_id of 6 but there is no Post 6.

Comment: @bgadoci, do you see the problem yet? You have comments with `post_id`   = `nil` and some with `post_id` that points to Posts that no longer exist. You need to fix your data before you can expect it to perform the reliably. I updated my post to show another option.

Comment: Man, I can't tell you how much I appreciate all the help. I am so new to all of this (programming and rails) that it is hard to get on here with such smart people. Thanks you so much that worked great.

Comment: @bgadoci, no problem. Never be afraid to ask questions. Just be thankful there's places like StackOverflow. I would've done anything for a resource like this when I was starting out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `<%=h comment.post.title %>` to output the title of the post associated with the comment.

Comment: I get the following error when I do that: undefined method `posts' for #<Comment:0x10420f990>. Do I also have to set something in the CommentsController Index action?

Comment: Did you try `comment.post.title` (singular) or `comment.posts.title`? The latter won't work.

Comment: Did you do `comment.post.title`? Notice the singular post. I think you typed `comment.psots.title`.

Comment: singular, just like you typed. Getting the same problem when I add anything after comment.post.whatever. BUT, when I just put <%=h comment.post %> it renders the actual post id record in the posts table (presumably), i.e. #<Post:0x1044dadc8>

Comment: so, just to clarify, when I add <%=h comment.post.title %>, I am getting an error saying that 'title' is an undefined method. If I change to body, I get the same 'undefined method' error but for body. It only seems to 'connect' to the post information when I leave it as <%=h comment.post %> in which case it t renders the actual post id record in the posts table (presumably), i.e. #<Post:0x1044dadc8>.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `script/console` and do `Post.column_names`?

Comment: It gives me the following: ["id", "title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at"]

Comment: It is interesting, when I run the @comments = Comment.find(:all, :include => :post, :order => "created_at DESC") in the script/console it appears to list all column information except the title. After realizing that, I went back to the /views/comments/index.html.erb file and tried <%=h comment.post.body %> but that also gave me the undefined method for 'body' even though it was in the script/console output. Perhaps it is something having to do with routes or the model?

Answer (score 0):

try @post.comment.title.Since post has many comment belongs to post,then is a kind of parent child relationship.